# Fuseki: First query after start and updates very slow

Tags: performance, sparql, owl, fuseki, reasoning

I got a little KB with 25000 Triples and 10 OWL Reasoning Rules (EquivalentClasses).

After a lot of work and desparation i got my Fuseki to work (OWLMicroFBRuleReasoner).

I get reasoned results in like 5ms. My big problem is that the first query after Fuseki starts OR after i inserted some data takes like 50 seconds.

What am i doing wrong? Is it because it does a full reasoning over the whole KB everytime?

**How could i fasten it up?**

Best regards...

Comment: most likely because if the recomputation of (aprts of) the inferred graph. Once this was done, it's cached and must only be recomputed again indeed after start or you changed the dataset. You can avoid this only if you materialize all inferences and load it into your triple store.

Comment: If i would split the update part (kind of a User-Model) and the readonly part (Recipes etc) it should the solution because the the reasoning rules are only on the readonly part. Ist this right or am i on the woodway?

Comment: if the rules do only work on the read-only part, you should materialize those inferences once and load this materialized model without enabling the rules.